# Connecting Amazon S3 bucket to Other Server - IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to connect Amazon S3 to other services through Bucket policy.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID:user/augmen",
      }

      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::rajatv.input",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::rajatv.input/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Still getting errors like:

1. This policy contains invalid Json
2. Invalid Bucket syntax
3. No Resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are wanting to give bucket access to a specific IAM User. If so, the best way is to **put a policy on the IAM User** themselves, so that the permissions apply only to them.

This policy would grant bucket access to whichever user has it as an IAM policy. To add it, go to the user, **Add Inline Policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PermitBucketAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::rajatv.input",
                "arn:aws:s3:::rajatv.input/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket Policies, which are applied to the bucket itself, are best used to grant access to *everyone*, whereas an IAM policy is best for granting permissions to specific IAM Users, Groups and Roles.

Comment: i tried this but the Error: Missing required field Principal ?

Comment: Add it to an IAM User (via Inline Policy) -- not as a Bucket Policy. Because it is attached to a user, it does not require a Principal.

Answer (score 1):

Principal needs to have this format:

```
"Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:root"]},
```